# Converting unixtime to the number of days

Tags: python, unix

Is it possible to translate the result of **unix-time** (namely, the number of seconds since 1970, January 1) into the number of days?
**I'm not talking about the usual date YY.MM.DD.**
For example, I got the average user lifetime on the site based on movie ratings and want to translate this into the number of days.

I tried to search for information on other sources, but it says only about the usual date (YY.MM.DD)

Comment: You mean a timespan consisting of two timestamps in UNIX-time? E.g. date someone signed up until today? How about `days = (today-sign-up-date)/86400`?

Answer (score 1):

divide by 60 to get minutes then by 60 to get hours then by 24 to get days --> 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400

```
import time
print(time.time() / 86400)
```